# Looping XPath variables in robot framework keywords

Tags: selenium, robotframework

newbie to the robot framework. I am trying to have a for loop within the keywords.

- Max should be a numeric value of 9
- So the for loop will increase from
  1 to 9 and replace the variable that i inserted into the XPath

  ```
  *** Variables ***
  ${MAX}  9

  *** Keywords ***
  Go to data gov sg page
      [Arguments]     ${MAX}        

      :FOR    ${EACH}     IN  ${MAX}
      \   click element   xpath:/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[${EACH}]/a
  ```

Currently the issue now is that it is not looping and going straight to 9. Not looping from 1..2...9.

Would appreciate if someone can take a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems forgot to use range function you can do like-

```
 FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    1   ${MAX+1}

    click element   xpath:/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[${INDEX}]/a
 END
```

Reference - [new style of for loop in RF 3.1 release](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-3.1.rst#for-loop-enhancements)

Comment: 2 things - the upper bound in the range is not inclusive, so please change it to `${MAX + 1}`; better use the new loop style, this one will be depricated soon.

Comment: @TodorMinakov May i know how does the new loop style looks like?

Comment: Sure, it's the one described in full in the current user's guide, but I'm giving a link to v3.1 release notes, where it is summarized - https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-3.1.rst#for-loop-enhancements

Comment: @Dev Hi, what if i do not want to start from 1 but start to increase from e.g. 4000. Since max is 9, it will be 4001, 4002... 4009. Any idea? Or should i post a new question cause im still alittle confused with the for loop syntax

Comment: its simple `FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE 4001    4009+1`